# Android SDK multilanguage app - can I change language at compile time?

Tags: android, sdk, multilingual

Suppose I want to support several languages.  I have a lot of content that is language-specific -- e.g. spoken-word audio files. So the amount of storage used by each language is significant.  I am concerned about the size of the apk on a mobile device.  Can I compile for one language at a time?  Is there a directive in AndroidManifest.xml that will do this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@scrayne you will want to create **product flavors* in your gradle build:

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#product-flavors

That provides information on how to create them. Then you would add the correct files to the product flavor (language) that you want.

Comment: This is just what I need.  Thanks.